# ZF2 Server Requirements/Recommendations

Tags: apache, zend-framework2, hardware

Hi I did a search on what would be the recommended or atleast requirements to run a nifty zf2 application.

I know I need PHP 5.3.3 or higher, but what abou the RAM and CPU requirements?

I found nothing. Magento for example needs A LOT of resources to run smooth, but I found nothing comparable for ZF2.

Have you guys met any experiences? Let me know.

Comment: This is really dependent on what you have implemented on top of ZF. For example MAgento needs a ton of resources not because its based on ZF1 but because of how the EAV system works and the huge configuration stack. Start with profiling your application to get a baseline and then work from there.

Comment: impossible to answer really as you've said nothing about the application. That's like asking how much fuel does a car use without specifying what kind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of answer is really only one you'll be able to answer yourself by loading up your application and testing. Depending on your application you may need more resources than the typical application would.

You mentioned Magento so here is a link to their requirements:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

However this still won't fully answer your question. There are many factors involved here such as the web server you will be running. Other applications running on the same machine. The amount of users you will have at any given type. There really is no true calculator to define what resources you'll need.

ZF2 specifically does not have many system requirements but you can find more information on that here: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html

If you're just throwing a machine together to test with, then you'd probably be fine with a 20+ gig hard drive and 2 Gigs of ram to get started.

Comment: well i was hoping for some people meantioning stuff like "I run a simple blog, have about 1,5k users a day. 512MB RAM 1GB core. Everything runs smooth"

Comment: As my experience as a sysadmin working for a large hosting company our Control Panel Server had 24 gigs of ram and was a dual-core Intel CPU. It may have been overkill, but it got the job done. I checked the specs for our current Magento Server and we've got it running on 8 gigs of ram and a dual-core Intel CPU. We are currently receiving roughly 8000 hits a day and we have 12 copies of Magento running on that machine and so far no issues.